# How can I get "Build Agent Folder" from inside a custom build template?

Tags: templates, msbuild

I'm trying to get hold of the "Build Agent Folder" from to use in a custom build template. I know I can reach properties by Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables but I cannot find anything that gives me the "Build Agent Folder"

Since I want to use the custom template for several projects and wants to be able to set different "Build Agent Folder" for each I need to read this property from somewhere. Is there some other place that I can read to find this property?

Is there any MSBuild $ style of property that holds this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GetBuildDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_GetBuildDirectory) activity in the process template. In MSBuild you can use `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` to get the current directory of the running script.

If you have multiple mappings, access them with [`Workspace.Folders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.folders.aspx).

```
  <ForEach x:TypeArguments="mtvc:WorkingFolder" DisplayName="ForEach WorkingFolder" Values="[Workspace.Folders]">
    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="mtvc:WorkingFolder">
      <ActivityAction.Argument>
        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="mtvc:WorkingFolder" Name="folder" />
      </ActivityAction.Argument>
      <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage Message="[String.Format(&quot;'{0}' mapped to '{1}'&quot;, folder.ServerItem, folder.LocalItem)]" />
    </ActivityAction>
  </ForEach>
```

Also instead of using `$(SourceDir)` you can use `$(BuildDir)` in the build definition which will bring you one level up.

Comment: Well that doesn't work. In Visual studio and the build definition I specify for example "$(SourceDir)\Release-Proj1" as my build agent folder but "GetBuildDirectory" only gives me "D:\Sources\Agent1"

The full path should be "D:\Sources\Agent1\src\Release-Proj1"

Comment: If you don't map more than one mapping folder, keep it just `$(SourceDir)`. Or you can try the value of `"[System.IO.Path.Combine(SourcesDirectory, &quot;Release-Proj1&quot;)]"`

Comment: That would work if the template is just for one project but we are using branches (CI, Release, Production..) and want to use the same template for all of the branches. We also share the build server with other projects so we want to have different folders for all projects. I find it strange that the value entered in that field can't be accessed from withing the template.